# How to get artifact out of docker build?

Tags: docker, docker-build

Is there a way to get artifacts from `docker build` out to the host machine?

As an example, given the following `Dockerfile`, is there a way to get the file `log.log`?

```
FROM alpine:3.7 as base
RUN mkdir /log/
RUN touch /log/log.log
```

---

My attempt at using `COPY` seems to only work copying *from* host *to* docker image:

```
FROM alpine:3.7 as base
RUN mkdir /log/
RUN touch /log/log.log
COPY ./foo.bar /log/
RUN ls -l /log/
COPY /log/log.log ./
```

```
$ touch ./foo.bar && docker build -t demo --no-cache .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  15.36kB
Step 1/6 : FROM alpine:3.7 as base
 ---> 6d1ef012b567
Step 2/6 : RUN mkdir /log/
 ---> Running in 4b6df3797ee3
Removing intermediate container 4b6df3797ee3
 ---> 827e6001d34a
Step 3/6 : RUN touch /log/log.log
 ---> Running in d93d50d61b69
Removing intermediate container d93d50d61b69
 ---> c44620d4f9c4
Step 4/6 : COPY ./foo.bar /log/
 ---> 6996718d44da
Step 5/6 : RUN ls -l /log/
 ---> Running in 84e997af182b
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov  8 21:44 foo.bar
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov  8 21:44 log.log
Removing intermediate container 84e997af182b
 ---> 5a440f258772
Step 6/6 : COPY /log/log.log ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder677155266/log/log.log: no such file or directory
```

---

I'm aware of the `-v` (volume mount) argument to `docker run` - but that's not what I'm looking for: I'm looking to learn if there's a way to get artifacts from out of the `docker build` process specifically.

---

**Update:** RE: @ChristianFosli's suggestion to use `docker cp`: that solution requires a docker *container*. However, in my case, the reason I am looking to extract files specifically during the `docker build` process is that my `Dockerfile` runs an executable that fails, therefore I have no image that I can run as a container on which I can perform the `docker cp`. I.e. the file that I would like to extract from the `docker build` process is a metadata file that contains debugging information about the failure, that I'd like to inspect.

Comment: Very current versions of Docker appear to have a way to dump the built image; the linked question has the syntax.  It may help your "update" use case to know that the 12-digit hex IDs that `docker build` prints out along the way are valid Docker image IDs, so you can `docker run --rm -it 5a440f258772 sh` to get an interactive debugging shell on a partially-built image.

Comment: @DavidMaze - confirming what you explained: I can indeed do `docker run --rm -it` of those "intermediate" docker images, and get my file that way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can copy files from a container to your local filesystem using `docker cp`.

[Check the docs for details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

I don't know of a way to copy files *directly* from a docker image, but you can create a container based on your image, without running it, with [docker create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/), and then copy files from it with `docker cp`.

Comment: Unfortunately, my specific problem is that my Dockerfile runs executables that fail (return status is nonzero), therefore a docker image is not generated, and therefore I don't have an image to run as a container. Therefore I was trying to get debug information from the `docker build` process itself. Sorry: my intent was to simplify the scope of my question, but I guess that was pertinent information. I will update the question.

Comment: Aah, that makes sense, no worries :-)